# NestJs, TypeOrm) Delete request with 2 Params

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I want to allow only the author of the post to remove the post from the db.

When requesting delete from controller, typeORM intended delte({id, user}) by sending post ID and user information together, but an error occurs.

```js
//entity

@Entity()
export class Board extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @Column()
  status: BoardStatus;

  @ManyToOne((type) => UserEntity, (user) => user.boards, { eager: false })
  user: UserEntity;
}
```

```js
// controller

  @Delete(':id')
  deleteBoard(
    @Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number,
    @GetUser() user: UserEntity,
  ): Promise<void> {
    return this.boardService.deletBoard(id, user);
  }
```

```js
// service

  async deletBoard(id: number, user: UserEntity): Promise<void> {
    const result = await this.boardRepository.delete({ id, user });

    /* Argument of type '{ id: number; user: UserEntity; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date | ObjectID | string[] | number[] | Date[] | ObjectID[] | FindOptionsWhere<Board>'.
  Types of property 'user' are incompatible. */

    if (result.affected === 0)
      throw new NotFoundException(`Can't find by ${id}`);
  }
```

Comment: can yo show user.entity & typeorm version

Answer (score 0):

try **createQueryBuilder()**:

```
await this.boardService.createQueryBuilder('board')
.leftJoin('board.user', 'user')
.where('board.id = :id', {id})
.andWhere('user.id = :id', {id: user.id})
.delete()
.execute();
```